# Codeigniter not showing proper results for array fetched by MySQL query.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am working with Codeigniter with mysql databases, 
I have a model function

```
public function get_all_data(){
    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    $years = $this->input->post('year');
    $months = $this->input->post('month');
    $exec_ids = $this->input->post('exec_id');
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM client_booking AS cb
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN executive_client_unit_relation AS ecur ON cb.id = ecur.booking_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN new_invoice ON cb.id = new_invoice.booking_id
        WHERE ecur.executive_id IN (" . implode(',', $exec_ids) . ") AND MONTH(cb.booking_date) IN (" . implode(',', $months) . ") AND YEAR(cb.booking_date) IN (" . implode(',', $years) . ")");
    return $query->result();
}
```

The sql generated by this is (as seen in the profiler) :

```
SELECT * FROM client_booking AS cb 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN executive_client_unit_relation AS ecur ON cb.id = ecur.booking_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN new_invoice ON cb.id = new_invoice.booking_id 
        WHERE ecur.executive_id IN (4,5,6) AND MONTH(cb.booking_date) IN (1,2,3,4,5) AND YEAR(cb.booking_date) IN (2013,2014)
```

My problem is that the `booking_id` value is set to `NULL` when I `var_dump()` the result of this query.
On the other hand, when I run the SQL in my phpmyadmin, everything goes well and I can see the booking_id

PS: `client_booking` table's primary key is `id` which is the `booking_id` for all the other tables.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `LEFT/RIGHT` joins so when there is no association found between your tables a null row will be returned ,second thing is your tables `new_invoice` and `executive_client_unit_relation` both have common names for the column name `booking_id` and in your select statement you are doing `select *` so for the columns with same name i guess the last one is picked which is null,for the solution you either you select only needed columns not all like `SELECT cb.*` or either the columns have same name with your query table then specify them individually with the alias you wish to provide but in the end of select statement in query like `SELECT *,cb.id AS booking_id,....`